# jQuery split text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a credit card field that populates a `<span>` tag e.g

```
<span>****-****-****-1111 (Expires 12/2012)</span>
```

I need to extract the date and find out if it is in the past.

At the moment I have the below jQuery but I'm stuck at the point of split() to extract just the date.

```
var $selectedDate = $('.prev-card .chzn-container .chzn-single span').text().split();
var $now = new Date();
if ($selectedDate < $now) {
    alert('past')
}
else{
    alert('future')
}
```

I think that covers everything but feel free to ask for more info

Comment: why are you doing this thing with client-side instead of server side?

Comment: @AnkitGautam Maybe it's to avoid a round-trip to the server when something trivial can be detected client-side? I'm trusting there's similar validation on the server-side too.

Comment: What is that .split() good for?

Comment: Not good for anything, that's the whole point of asking the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selectedDate = $("...").text().match(/Expires (\d+)\/(\d+)/),
    expires = new Date(selectedDate[2],selectedDate[1]-1,1,0,0,0),
    now = new Date();
if( expires.getTime() < now.getTime()) alert("past");
else alert("future");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt split it. I would use a regex:

```
var value = $('.prev-card .chzn-container .chzn-single span').text();
/\d+\/\d+/.exec(value)   //["12/2012"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Small fix to Kolink's answer:

```
var selectedDate = $("...").text().match(/Expires (\d+)\/(\d+)/),
    expires = new Date(selectedDate[2],selectedDate[1]-1,1,0,0,0),
    now = new Date();
if( expires.getTime() < now.getTime()) alert("past");
else alert("future");
```

(regexp doesn't need quotes)